# Laravel query results in a complex join scenario

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5 and I have 4 tables

**payroll_template**

```
id | salary_grade | basic_salary
```

**payroll_allowance**

```
id |template_id | allowance_label | allowance_value
```

**payroll_deduction**

```
id | template_id | deduction_label | deduction_value
```

**payroll_payment**

```
id | template_id | user_id
```

I want to join these tables `payroll_template`, `payroll_allowance`, `payroll_payment` and `payroll_deduction`  and put the field value of `allownce_label` and `deduction_label` as the column name and `allownce_value` and `deduction_value`   as their colomn value from respective tables .

if the users doesn't have  allownce_label but others users  contains than put the allownce value 0.
same for deduction.

I want to show results as

```
user_id | salary_grade | basic_salary | allowance_label | deduction_label
```

The `allowance_label` and `deduction_label` values  should come in in their respective column

Answer (score 1):

try this query :

```
   DB::table('payroll_payment')
    ->join('payroll_template', 'payroll_payment. user_id', '=', 'payroll_template.user_id')
    ->join('payroll_allowance', 'payroll_payment. template_id', '=', 'payroll_allowance.template_id')
    ->join('payroll_deduction', 'payroll_payment. template_id', '=', 'payroll_deduction.template_id')
    ->select('payroll_payment.*','payroll_template.salary_grade','payroll_template. basic_salary','payroll_allowance.allowance_label','payroll_allowance. allowance_value','payroll_deduction.deduction_label','payroll_deduction.deduction_value'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: actually there is no user_id in payroll_template